# How can I convert a UTC 24 hour time to another timezone? (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, python-3.9

I get a 24-hour UTC time from an API which I need to convert to a different timezone. Both the year, month, day, and minutes are completely redundant and useless to me.

This function would basically be like this website: https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/utc-to-aest-converter (in 24-hour mode) but dynamic and programmatic. If somebody can share how to do this conversion I can extrapolate it and create the function myself.

The timezone that I am converting to has to be able to be changed as if it was a parameter in the function. The result does not need to be a DateTime object, could just be an integer of the converted hour.

Thanks for helping! Python 3.9

Comment: UTC offsets of different time zones change over the year (and have also been changed in the past for political reasons) - so basically, without a date, this doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really simple way to do it.

```
transformed_time = (utc_time + shift) % 24
```

I originally just didn't know this is how timezones worked, but it works perfectly, if you don't know the 'shift' of your timezone, look up "UTC offset to *your timezone*".

Comment: what if the "shift" is e.g. +5:30 h as it is in India? - that will give you fractional hours; how do you handle those?